# I accidentally added a widget area called sidebar 1

Tags: widgets

I accidentally added a widget area called sidebar 1 (because I was an idiot and read the instructions in the Widget Name area wrong). Now it's currently conflicting with my Theme Sidebar (theme is Divi Elegant Themes). Went I load the blog page of the website, the sidebar 1 shows up instead of the default sidebar.

Is there any way to remove this new widget area without breaking the entire website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a line like this in your functions.php of the theme:

"register_sidebar"...

```
 <?php
    // ... some code before
    // 
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('unwanted widget', 'your-textdomain'),
        'description' => __('Your new widget desciption', 'your-textdomain'),
        'id'            => 'your-new-widget-name'
    ));

    // ...some code after
 ?>
```

Search for that line and change it. Basically, simply rename your unwanted Sidebar 1 to something different.

You have overwritten the default widget with a new one and created a name conflict. Change the name of your unwanted widget, that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've already tried looking for register_sidebar in the functions.php file but couldn't find it.

There is register_nav_menus, register_post_type and register_taxonomy but no register_sidebar

Comment: Sorry, that this didn't help you, I think I/we need more code to find the problem.

Comment: What code specifically do you need?

P.S. There is a sidebar.php file

Comment: It would be good to know, what you did in first place, as this caused all your trouble. Are there any chances you can reproduce what you did? I don't want you to mess it all up with my "glassball" solutions.. I'll check back later tonight. I still believe it is a name conflict.

Comment: In the Widgets area of Appearance there is a section that lets you create a Widget Area. It asks you to add a widget name and click on the "create" button. I accidentally created the widget area "sidebar-1" without thinking. I think it probably registers the widget area using this method. Unfortunately, it doesn't let you unregister, delete or rename it once it's created. I think you are correct in saying it's a name conflict (as it warns that there will be one if I use a name like that) but I don't know where to locate it to fix it.

Comment: Actually apparently there's more than one theme with a functions.php file. Unfortunately I found the register_sidebar in all of them. How do I know which one is the correct one?

Comment: 1) You definitely need to find out, which theme you are using. In addition, you need check if this theme uses a child theme. 2) As it sounds from a distance, your theme has some additional functionality in the backend, which let's you add and edit the amount of widget bars it has. Now, that is pretty tricky and it would be best to ask the developer of the theme. Last and most dangerous option would be to look in the database, if there are duplicates in the table, where the widget information is stored. Whatever you do, make sure to export/copy that database as a backup.

Comment: It looks like there are a couple of child themes: titles "twenty fifteen", "twenty fourteen", "twenty thirteen". Each of these has a functions.php file, each of which have a register_sidebar function.  I would have asked the developer by now but unfortunately it's a paid theme with a subscription service and the subscription has expired. You have to be an active subscriber to ask questions.

Comment: But you should know, which theme you have paid for, right? Go to > Appearance > Themes > look for the first theme in the upper left, which has the black bar at the bottom and says "active: bla bla bla". That is the thing you need to investigate!

Comment: Yeah, the Divi theme is the active one but like I mentioned earlier it doesn't have the register_sidebar array in the functions.php file. A couple of the child themes do but I don't know which one the main theme must be pulling from (if it's pulling from it at all). I've decided to just leave it as is for now until I can get hold of the developer. Thanks for all your help though!